# TileMill - nice style for osm data in OS Windows

Tags: openstreetmap, shapefile, tilemill, cartocss

can you tell me what is the simpliest way to add style for my shape extracts from mapzen and give me some hint how do that in windows, becouse the majoritz of tutorials are for linux or mac oc. I need also help to choose the correct shape files from mapzen, there are 2 ways:

- datasets split by by geometry type: lines, points or polygons
- datasets grouped into individual layers by OpenStreetMap tags

I need import shape into tilemill, add nice style (for exmaple this: https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright), and next export to *.mbtiles.

Comment: TIleMill works on Windows too (last time I tried, quite a while), and the styling should work the same. What step are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have trouble with sld style :/ I found this https://github.com/FlorentDotMe/archives/tree/master/2013.03.23-OSM-Styles-for-GeoServer but when I import data into postgis and next connect  it to geoserver as data source and add these styles, works only style for line. Polygon not, but I do know why ... do you have any ideas what could be wrong or how to use it ?